# how to get messages from linked discussion group of channels with telethon

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I have already successfully retrieved messages from channels.
I do that with the iter_messages function
However, the message object does not contain the comments, only the users wrote the comments.
In the object is a channel_id, this seems to be the linked group. But the group doesn't have a URL like t.me/xxx. Does anyone have an approach for a solution?

Here is an excerpt from the object as JSON.

```
 "replies": {
  "_": "MessageReplies",
  "replies": 8,
  "replies_pts": 17846,
  "comments": true,
  "recent_repliers": [
    {
      "_": "PeerUser",
      "user_id": 57135752
    },
    {
      "_": "PeerUser",
      "user_id": 564589817
    },
    {
      "_": "PeerUser",
      "user_id": 888542547
    }
  ],
  "channel_id": 1484030956,
  "max_id": 13402,
  "read_max_id": null
},
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found a solution which is working fine.
When you have the specific message id you can set the flag reply_to. Then you get the comments of the channel posts.

```
def get_comments(client: TelegramClient, channel: str, message_id: int):
    async def crawl_comments():
        async for message in client.iter_messages(channel, reply_to=message_id):
            print(message.text)  # only comment
            full_comment_obj = message.to_dict()  # in JSON-Format
            print(full_comment_obj)

    with client:
       client.loop.run_until_complete(crawl_comments())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you had joined to this group manually, It can work.

```
async for message in client.iter_messages(peer):
    if message.replies:
        channel_peer = types.InputChannel(message.replies.channel_id, 0)
        chat = await client.get_entity(channel_peer)
```

But better way is to get full channel request, so you can get a channel itself and chat as an entities (and maybe join it?), then find if any of them are replies to channel post.

```
chat_full = await client(functions.channels.GetFullChannelRequest(peer))
channel = chat_full.chats[0]

chat = channel_full.linked_chat_id
if chat:
    chat = chat_full.chats[-1]

async for message in client.iter_messages(peer):
    msg_data = {
        "id": message.id,
        "date": message.date,
        "message": message.message,
    }
    if chat:
        msg_data["replies"] = client.get_messages(chat, reply_to=message.id)
```

This code is untested, but I am working on it o_0

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try this and give feedback.